# Magento custome option product in search result

Tags: magento

I am uploading an product and product  has different  size  available, Now if customer- who want to buy this, they have to select size then  after they can buy. How to do this. I knew custom option is available in magento. But i want to allow customer to search product by size also, so what should i do to perform this type of things?. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use custom options for different sizes. This is why you have **configurable products**.

You make a configurable product and then link it to simple products which represent its sizes.

Then for the simple product you select visibility: search (to show it on search).

`Custom product options` are **NOT** used in search and there is nothing you can do to use them in search (apart from building a very complex module).

Another solution would be to put the values from the custom options inside an attribute which has `Use in Advanced Search` and `Use in Quick Search` to yes.

Comment: Thanks. great help And if i want advance search option for size in all page as like simple search then how can we do? can help?

Answer (score 0):

First of all for using the type you can use any(both configurable or custom options) but should know which is more suitable.If you have large variety of options than Configurable product is a good option but if there is less variety than you can also use custom option as your wish.

Now another part of the question you want to make it searchable according to size right? In your sense searching means filtering in layered navigation or what? For both searching or filtering doesnot have relation on the product type. If you want filtering of the product according to size than you have to create an attribute size.This could help.

Hope this will help.